# Task Instance State Task is in the 'queued' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run. Airflow task

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, airflow-scheduler, airflow

Kubernetes Pod describes as above, and it says it is using local executor instead of Kubernetes executor and invalid image. Pod log shows as below

```
kubectl describe pod tablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc
            Name:         swedschematablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc
            Namespace:    default
            Priority:     0
            Node:         10.73.96.181
            Start Time:   Mon, 11 May 2020 18:22:15 +0530
            Labels:       airflow-worker=5888feda-6aee-49c8-a94b-39cbe5758062
                          airflow_version=1.10.10
                          dag_id=Swed-schema-tables-creation
                          execution_date=2020-05-11T12_52_09.829627_plus_00_00
                          kubernetes_executor=True
                          task_id=Schema_Tables_Creation
                          try_number=1
            Annotations:  <none>
            Status:       Pending
            IP:           172.17.0.46
            IPs:
              IP:  172.17.0.46
            Containers:
              base:
                Container ID:
                Image:         :
                Image ID:
                Port:          <none>
                Host Port:     <none>
                Command:
                  airflow
                  run
                  Swed-schema-tables-creation
                  Schema_Tables_Creation
                  2020-05-11T12:52:09.829627+00:00
                  --local
                  --pool
                  default_pool
                  -sd
                  /root/airflow/dags/User_Creation_dag.py
                State:          Waiting
                  Reason:       InvalidImageName
                Ready:          False
                Restart Count:  0
                Environment:
                  AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:          LocalExecutor
                  AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN:  postgresql://airflowkube:airflowkube@10.73.96.181:5434/airflowkube
                Mounts:
                  /root/airflow/dags from airflow-dags (ro)
                  /root/airflow/logs from airflow-logs (rw)
                  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-64cxg (ro)
            Conditions:
              Type              Status
              Initialized       True
              Ready             False
              ContainersReady   False
              PodScheduled      True
            Volumes:
              airflow-dags:
                Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
                Path:          /data/Naveen/Airflow/dags
                HostPathType:
              airflow-logs:
                Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
                Path:          /data/Naveen/Airflow/Logs
                HostPathType:
              default-token-64cxg:
                Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
                SecretName:  default-token-64cxg
                Optional:    false
            QoS Class:       BestEffort
            Node-Selectors:  <none>
            Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
            Events:
              Type     Reason         Age                     From                           Message
              ----     ------         ----                    ----                           -------
              Normal   Scheduled      <unknown>               default-scheduler              Successfully assigned default/swedschematablescreationschematablescreation-ecabd38a66664a33b6645a72ef056edc to evblfnclnullnull1538
              Warning  Failed         2m15s (x12 over 4m28s)  kubelet, evblfnclnullnull1538  Error: InvalidImageName
              Warning  InspectFailed  2m (x13 over 4m28s)     kubelet, evblfnclnullnull1538  Failed to apply default image tag ":": couldn't parse image reference ":": invalid reference format
        **strong text**
        enter code here
```

Comment: add some more details and adding some explanation can help you get the answers

Comment: Kubernetes executor is creating the pod but with invalid image name. When i describe the pod it uses local executor even though configured with kubernetes executor.